# Moving a picture at the right

Tags: moderncv

I have my picture on cv at left, I want to move it at the right, I used the moderncv.

This is the head of my code:

```
 [![% Exemple de CV utilisant la classe moderncv
% Style classic en bleu

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm}

\firstname{Céline}
\familyname{Venditi}
\title{Data Scientist}              
\address{XXX}{YYY}    
\email{celine.venditi@gmail.com}                      
\mobile{07 89 41} 
\begin{document}
\includegraphics\[height=4cm, width=3cm, origin=r\]{captureimage1.png}\\
\maketitle]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\hfill` to add stretchable space to push the image to the other side.

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % Used for blank image

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm}

\firstname{Céline}
\familyname{Venditi}
\title{Data Scientist}              
\address{XXX}{YYY}    
\email{celine.venditi@gmail.com}                      
\mobile{07 89 41}

\begin{document}
\hfill\includegraphics[height=4cm, width=3cm]{captureimage1.png}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where I can add the \hfill; Like this \hspace*{\fill}

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your modification, Thank you very much! it working fine!

Answer (score 2):

Here it is: use a `flushright` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm}

\firstname{Céline}
\familyname{Venditi}
\title{Data Scientist}
\address{XXX}{YYY}
\email{celine.venditi@gmail.com}
\mobile{07 89 41}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=3cm, origin=r]{pepe-le-pew1}\end{flushright}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I suspect you rather want this, using the `\photo` command from moderncv:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm}

\firstname{Céline}
\familyname{Venditi}
\title{Data Scientist}
\address{XXX}{YYY}
\email{celine.venditi@gmail.com}
\mobile{07 89 41}
\photo[3cm][0pt]{pepe-le-pew1}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]