# CV: moving adress upwards

Tags: spacing, titles, moderncv

I tried to move my adress upwards to gain more space, but I can't do it. I used `\raisebox`.

My code is the following:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
    \moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[]{siunitx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
    % Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm}
    \firstname{Céline}
    \familyname{venditi}
    \title{Data Scientist, Ingénieur}
    \raisebox{8mm}[0pt][0pt]{            
    \address{AAAA}{ZZZZ}{YYY}    
    \email{celine.venditi@gmail.com}                      
    \mobile{07 89 41} 
    }
    \begin{document}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm, width=3cm]{IMG_20161029_182417.jpg}\\
    \maketitle
    \section{Formations}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

I just change my code, I used `\vspace`

```
  \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm}
    \firstname{Céline}
    \familyname{venditi}
    \title{Data Scientist, Ingénieur}
    %\raisebox{8mm}[0pt][0pt]{            
    \vspace{-4cm}\address{AAAA}{ZZZZ}{YYY}    
    \email{celine.venditi@gmail.com}                      
    %\homepage{www.madrzejewski.com}
    \mobile{07 89 41} 
    %}
    \begin{document}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm, width=3cm, origin=r]{IMG_20161029_182417.jpg}\\
    \maketitle
    \section{Formations}
```

But it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way of using [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)'s `classic` style is to use `\photo[<width>][<framewidth>]{<image>}` to set a photo. By default, this places the image as part of the header on the right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\firstname{First name}
\familyname{Last name}
\title{Personal title}
\address{First line}{Second line}{Third line}
\email{who@cares.com}
\mobile{1 23 456 7890}
\photo[3cm]{example-image-golden-upright}

\begin{document}

\makecvhead % ...or \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note this is what I proposed in my answer to your previous post.

Comment: Yeah, that's true! you proposed this solution.  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341590/moving-a-picture-at-the-right/341596#341596